# Django Rest Framework ModelSerializer get field data depending on query param

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a `ModelSerializer` with several field, many of them are `StringRelatedField` so the default representation of this fields is given by the `__str__` method on the model, in my case this are mostly `name` field in each model. In other cases I need to retrieve the `id` instead, so how can I do this, for example depending of a query param.

Comment: Custom field implementation with ```to_representation``` and ```to_internal_value``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving this way for now, please share if someone has a better solution:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        v = self.context['request'].query_params.get('v', None) # using v query param for a "variant" handling
        if v == '1': # one of my variants
            self.fields['examplefield'] = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=False, allow_null=True)
```

Note that there is no `else` or another `if` statement because I only needed two variants, one of them for retrieving the `name` field, the other for the `id`. By default DRF will use `PrimaryRelatedField` (which is the `id`) for `ModelSerializer` related fields see [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)